# Firebase google-services.json に client_id が含まれない

Tags: firebase

Firebase でプロジェクト作成 → Androidアプリの登録 → google-services.json のダウンロード を行った際、json 内に client_id の項目が含まれなくなってしまいました。(2023/9/12現在)
少なくとも 9/8 までは、同様(と記憶している)の手順でセットアップ/ダウンロードした json には含まれていました。

調べていくと、client_id があるプロジェクト/ないプロジェクトでの違いとして、Google Cloud Console の API とサービス > 認証情報 のページで下記の差異がありました。

```
OAuth 2.0 クライアント ID
iOS client for xxxxx (auto created by Google Service)
Web client (auto created by Google Service)
```

↑ client_id がないプロジェクトでは Web client 項目が生成されていない
(同様に iOS アプリを登録しても iOS client for~ は生成されない)

恐らくこの項目が Firebase 側の何かしらによって自動生成されていたものが生成されなくなったことで client_id が含まれなくなってしまったのかと推測しているのですが、どうすれば以前のように client_id が含まれた json が生成できるでしょうか。

手動で OAuth 2.0 クライアント ID の生成を行えばいいのかもしれませんが、従来の構成との違いによる影響の確認と、残り数十アプリ分の登録があり少々手間なため、できれば依然と同じ手順で登録したいと考えています。

解決策をお持ちの方や同様の状況になっている方いらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。

■ google-services.json の内容

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "0000000000",
    "project_id": "xxxxx",
    "storage_bucket": "xxxxx.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:000000000000:android:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [],       ← ここが空 ★★★
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
      ],
      "services": {
        "appinvite_service": {
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []     ← ここも空 ★★★
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```